# How to resolve the error "TypeError: i[k] is undefined" when reloading of jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Here I am trying to call onclick function to load the data in datatable,Reloading of datatable giving  error like "TypeError: i[k] is undefined".

```
function getAdvanceSearch()
{
 var $table=$('#MSRRes').dataTable( {
"bFilter": false,                         
"bDestroy": true,
"bDeferRender": false,
"bJQueryUI": true,
"oTableTools": {
    "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf",
},
"sDom": 'TC<"clear">l<"toolbar">frtip',
"ajax" :{
    url: 'getResult.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
       formData:postData,
     }  
},
"aoColumns": aryJSONColTable
});
}
```